Why does regex lookahead and lookbehind behave the same with anchor ^
I just read this answer and cannot wrap my head around why it works. It seems that both of these patterns (negative lookahead and negative lookbehind) will match a - not at the beginning of the string:
(?!^)-
(?<!^)-

Similarly a positive lookahead and positive lookbehind both behave the same and will match a - at the beginning of the string:
(?=^)-
(?<=^)-

But this behaviour only seems to apply to lookahead and lookbehind patterns when using an ^ anchor. In other words, they behave as expected below, where only the second pattern (positive lookbehind) will match X-.
(?=X)-
(?<=X)-

Can someone please explain the mechanics of this?

There are various implementations of regex, and not all have the same syntax (or, I'm guessing, semantics around edge cases). It could be useful to list exactly what language and regex library (if it's not built into the language) you're using.

@yshavit - My application in this case is javascript (browser) but I tried this in php, web console (js) and regex101.com and all seem to behave the same.

@yshavit This seems to be consistent across all the flavors that have lookahead at regex101.com.

I suspect it's because ^ is an assertion, not matching an actual string.

@Barmar - I assume the same, but still cannot wrap my head around what's actually going on :-) Would love a breakdown of the logic involved

^ is special case because it is a zero-width match

That sounds right. It basically requires that the same character be both X and -, because matching the lookahead doesn't move the matching position ahead.

But a lookbehind specifically means "go back and check if this is before the match".

Also maybe this wonderful artwork  helps in understanding!

this question is being discussed on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/431849/why-was-my-question-about-how-regex-lookarounds-work-considered-a-duplicate-of

Found an excellent explanation here as well  from Wiktor Stribiżew.

When the regex engine processes a lookahead, it checks whether the following part of the input matches the pattern, but it doesn't advance the position in the input. So if you have something after the lookahead, it must match at the same place as the lookahead.
This works fine when the lookahead contains a zero-width assertion like ^ or \b. But if it contains something that matches 1 or more characters, the pattern after the lookahead must match at the same place. Since X and - can't both match the same character, (?=X)- can never succeed. On the other hand, a pattern like (?=X.*).*- can work because .* allows the matching to include the portion that includes X.
Lookbehind work differently, since it's asserting that the text before the main pattern matches. It goes backwards, so it doesn't require the lookbehind match to be at the same place as the main match.
